# Any tips for preventing your horse from dying?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I keep running into the problem of my horse rushing in to join me in combat, which helps sometimes, but I often forget to heal him and he dies.

I have tried parking him a ways away, but he still seems to notice I am in battle and rushes over to join.

Can anyone give me some tips they have tried to remedy this problem?  Maybe buying a calming spell, or I suppose I could cheat and "resurrect" him after every battle, but there wouldn't be any fun in that now would there?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36266/is-there-a-way-to-stop-things-from-attacking-my-horse-npcs-and-to-pull-them-to-m

Comment: As far as keeping REGULAR horses alive... Well, Unless you park like 50 ft away, and run to the creatures, there isn't much hope. I went through 8k on horses...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you care to join the Dark Brotherhood, eventually you will get Shadowmere (she returns!) who cannot be killed.

All the horse on dragon action you love, none of the ragdoll horse death!

Comment: I think she can be killed, but her health and regen are so high its difficult to do so. I fell off a cliff and she died, but I didn't.

Answer (score 2):

With the exception of great steed placement and healing spells there isn't much you can do.  That animal just loves to stomp enemies...

Answer (score 2):

If you have a high enough Illusion skill, you can use the [***Calm*** or ***Fear***](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Illusion_Spells) spells or their [higher-level versions](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Illusion_Spells) to prevent your horse from getting involved in combat and possibly getting killed.

#### Playing on the PC

You could use the [`setessential` console command](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console_Commands#Targeted_Commands) to set your horse as unkillable.

The mod, **[Convenient Horses](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/14950/?)**, can set player-owned horses to flee at the sight of combat, rather than getting involved and killed.

It can also set your horse as 'essential' (i.e. unkillable) or increase your horse's health, preventing or lessening the chances of your horse getting killed. It also has other useful, optional horse-related features.

The [**Oblivious Horses**](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/13036/?) mod can set player-owned horses to not attack and be completely ignored by all hostile creatures and NPCs. It also has optional files that can set your horse to be unkillable.

There are also other [horse-related mods that have similar features (Nexus Mods search)](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/searchresults/?quicksrc_name=horses&quicksrc_auth=).

Answer (score 1):

If my horse insists on rushing into battle, I use the Kyne's Peace shout and that takes care of my horses righteous rage.