# How do you see your horse's health in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm tired of my horse dying because a mob gets a lucky shot or I don't start healing fast enough.

Is there a way to see your horse's health?

Answer (score 10):

There is no way to see your horse's health without attacking it yourself, sorry.

But for tips on how to keep your horse from dying, check out:

- [Any tips for preventing your horse from dying?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36413/any-tips-for-preventing-your-horse-from-dying)
- [Is there a way to stop things from attacking my horse/NPCs and to pull them to me? Or Stop my horse/NPCs running off into combat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36266/is-there-a-way-to-stop-things-from-attacking-my-horse-npcs-and-to-pull-them-to-m)

If you're willing to bend a few rules, you could also try resurrecting your horse [via the console](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console).

First, find the horse's PRID: you can do that by opening up the console, selecting the horse, and using the following command:

```
prid
```

Then, use the following command:

```
<prid>.ressurrect 1
```

Where `<prid>` is the PRID of the horse. This *should* resurrect your horse, good as new.

Answer (score 5):

So far, the only way that I've determined to see your horse's health is, to, well, uh, hit your horse. Then your horse's health bar is displayed.

Yeah.

...You might consider hitting the horse gently, say with your fists or something, to make sure that you don't end up inadvertently scaring it off or killing it.

Comment: Aslong as your not Khajiit ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you have the healing hands spell, you can cast it on your horse and see it's health bar.

Comment: This doesn't work with companions (healing them does not display health bar, unless they happen to be in a fight). Are you sure it does work with a horse?

Comment: It works for my companions when they are injured but not when they are fully healed.

Comment: Any time i've healed the horse it hasn't displayed a health bar. I get restoration skill so its obviously geting healed.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `getav health` on the console commands, by hitting the console key ( usually <kbd>~</kbd> or <kbd>'</kbd> ), clicking on the horse till it's refid shows and entering `getav health`? Something else to do would be to install the floating health bars mod but that only shows if the horse is in combat. If you install the convenient horses mod, you can select cowardly as your horse's behaviour so it just runs away from battle.