# At what level of an enemy will a horse run away instead of attacking?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have noticed that horses will attack some less-strong enemies but will run away from other enemies, especially dragons.

What level does an enemy have to be in order for a horse to run away instead of attacking?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to stop things from attacking my horse/NPCs and to pull them to me? Or Stop my horse/NPCs running off into combat?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36266/is-there-a-way-to-stop-things-from-attacking-my-horse-npcs-and-to-pull-them-to-m)

Comment: @fbueckert The question is not a duplicate imo. He's asking about the enemy level not how to stop the horse from attacking the enemy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all depends on the enemy level. Normal horse including Frost is a level 4 creature so it will attack any enemy below level 4. Exception for Shadowmere, it will attack any enemy insight (including dragons) because it is a badass level 50 horse.

Comment: 11 years later, I accepted your answer lol